# How to set up nested routes with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a Parent Container:

```
function Home() {
   render (
      <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/website" component={Website} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/website/web-one" component={WebOne} />
            <Route path="/website/web-two" component={WebTwo} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/dash-one" component={DashOne} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/dash-two" component={DashTwo} />
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   )
}
```

And both the Website and Dashboard each has their route that I want to render based on what is on the url. Here's what I did so far:

```
    //home
    function Website(){
      render (
          <div>
             <div>Welcome to Website page</div>
             <Router>
               <Switch>
                  <Route path="/website/web-one" component={WebOne} />
                  <Route path="/website/web-two" component={WebTwo} />
               </Switch>
             </Router>
          </div>
      )
    }
   
    //dashboard
    function Dashboard(){
      render (
          <div>
             <div>Welcome to Dashboard page</div>
               <Router>
                  <Switch>
                     <Route path="/dashboard/dash-one" component={DashOne} />
                     <Route path="/dashboard/dash-two" component={DashTwo} />
                  </Switch>
               </Router>
           </div>
      )
    }
```

How can I make sure that both nested routes displays perfectly well on their respective parents and both parent titles remain the same.

Currently, I'm getting this error:

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours, I got it fixed and what I did was remove the `<Router>` tag that wraps both child component of Home from their respective components. Because it was like having a Router inside a another Router.

Also, I remove the extra Routes from the Home component and write them in their respective parent components.

Now the `Home` component looks like this:

```
   function Home() {
      render (
         <Router>
            <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/" component={Website} />
               <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
         </Router>
      )
   }
```

And the other two child routes like this:

```
    //home
    function Website(){
      render (
          <div>
             <div>Welcome to Website page</div>
               <Switch>
                  <Route path="/website/one" component={WebOne} />
                  <Route path="/website/two" component={WebTwo} />
               </Switch>
          </div>
      )
    }
   
    //dashboard
    function Dashboard(){
      render (
          <div>
             <div>Welcome to Dashboard page</div>
                  <Switch>
                     <Route path="/dashboard/one" component={DashOne} />
                     <Route path="/dashboard/two" component={DashTwo} />
                  </Switch>
           </div>
      )
    }
```